# Prove that $H_n - H_m > \frac{n-m}{n}$ for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n > m \geq 1$, by doing induction on $n$ and base case $n = m$

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Problem:

Let $H_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} $ for all natural numbers $n \geq 1$.

Prove that $H_n - H_m \geq \frac{n-m}{n}$ for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n > m \geq 1$, by doing induction on $n$, letting $m$ be any natural number, and starting with the base case $n = m$.

$--------------------------------------$

I have done the base case, but I am confused on how to start with the inductive step.

We want to show that

$H_{n+1} - H_m \geq \frac{n+1-m}{n+1}$

Proof:

Base Case:

Let $n = m$, then $H_m - H_m \geq \frac{m-m}{m} = 0 \geq 0$, this is true.

Inductive Step:

Let P(n) denote the statement $H_n - H_m \geq \frac{n-m}{n}$.

We need to show that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, so we need to prove  $H_{n+1} - H_m \geq \frac{n+1-m}{n+1}$

Then,

$H_{n+1} - H_m = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} - (\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{m})$

$= \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} \geq \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{n-m}{n}$, by the inductive hypothesis

$= \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} \geq 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n-m}{n}$

$= \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} \geq 1 + \frac{n+1-m}{n}$

which is $ > \frac{n+1-m}{n+1}$

I think this is a dud, since I proved $>$, and not $\geq$. Does anyone have any recommendations? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please do not use the harmonic-functions tag, that is for something else

Comment: @CalvinKhor apologies. I am somewhat new and I rollbacked to my previous edit because I had a tiny mistake. I did not realize it put the tag back.

Comment: I saw the history, no harm done. Sorry I can't help with your problem though

Comment: Why induction? $H_n-H_m=\frac{1}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+2}  +...+ \frac{1}{n} > \frac{n - m}{n}$ by direct estimation of each fraction.

Comment: @MartinR asked to use induction specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you are subtracting the sums

$H_{n+1} - H_m = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{n+1} - \Big(1 + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{m}) = $

$ = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m+1} + ... + \frac{1}{n+1} - \Big(1 + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{m}) $

$ = \frac{1}{m+1} + ... + \frac{1}{n+1} $

since the first m terms of $H_{n+1}$ cancel out the terms of $H_m$. But this is not very helpful for induction. You must say the following,

$ H_{n+1} - H_m = \frac{1}{n+1} + H_n - H_m \geq \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{n-m}{n} $

where the last inequality holds because of the induction hypothesis. Now, by rearranging terms it's easy to prove that

$ \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{n-m}{n} \geq \frac{n+1-m}{n+1} $

Which implies that

$ H_{n+1} - H_m \geq \frac{n+1-m}{n+1} $

Now about using the equality or not is not a big problem. But, if u want to have only use ">", your first step in induction should be for $n=m+1$, and not $n=m$, since $m+1$ is the first natural number $>m$.

Comment: I am confused about $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{n-m}{n} \geq \frac{n+1-m}{n+1}$. Take $n = 2$, and $m = 1$, the smallest possible values for both, these will never be $=$, but will always be $>$, which is why I am concerned for my proof, since I am proving $H_{n+1} - H_m > \frac{n+1-m}{n+1}$, and not $H_{n+1} - H_m \geq \frac{n+1-m}{n+1}$.

Comment: nevermind... just received word that $n >= m >= 1$... there was a typo with the problem on the assignment. this is a perfect, explanation, thank you so much!

Comment: When proving that $H_{n+1} - H_m > \frac{n+1-m}{n+1}$, there is a mistake when subtracting your sums $H_{n+1}$ and $H_{m}$. The value of 

$H_{n+1} - H_m = \frac{1}{n+1} + H_n - H_m$.

Now look again how you are going from the first line to the second. You say that 

$H_{n+1} - H_m = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}$

Comment: You can also see that from the line where you are using the inductive hypothesis. Removing the equal terms from both sides you get $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} \geq \frac{n-m}{n}$. Now this for n=2 and m=1 gives $-\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2}$, which obviously is not a case.